# C# String array modifcation without recursion

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array with values

```
patrick 
portland 
vic
```

and I want to achieve the following:

for the first pass I want to have an array with * appended to the end of each entry:

```
patrick*
portland*
vic*
```

for second pass, I want to replace * with a ~:

```
patrick*
portland*
vic~

patrick*
portland~
vic*

patrick~
portland*
vic*
```

for third pass, I want to replace another * with ~:

```
patrick~
portland*
vic~

patrick~
portland~
vic*

patrick*
portland~
vic~
```

and so on until all the * are replaced by ~.

Is there a way do it without recursion?

Edit 1:

Need the following strings generated based on: patrick portland vic

```
patrick*portland*vic*
patrick*portland*vic~
patrick*portland~vic*
patrick~portland*vic*
patrick~portland*vic~
patrick~portland~vic*
patrick*portland~vic~
patrick~portland~vic~
```

I thought it would be easier to split the string into an array and then work on.

***Edit 2:***

Managed to solve this using cartesian product.

```
    string[] stnameSplit = streetName.Split(' ');

    string[] chars = { "*", "~" };
    var cartesianProduct = from name in stnameSplit
                           from cha in chars
                           select new { name, cha };

    List<string> vals = cartesianProduct.Select(p => p.name + p.cha).ToList();

        List<List<string>> embeddedList = new List<List<string>>();

        int ctr = 0;

        List<string> l = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in vals)
        {
            l.Add(s);

            if (ctr % 2 == 1)
            {
                embeddedList.Add(l);

                l = new List<string>();
            }

            ctr++;
        }

        var result = embeddedList.ToArray().CartesianProduct();
```

The last line calls the method CartesianProduct as described by Eric Lippert.

Thanks everyone for the help and guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: I cant understand why you need multiple passes, or how pass 2 and 3 actually work, this is confusing to say the least

Comment: There's always a way to do it without recursion; recursion is just a fancy way to write a loop. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Can you show us a recursive algorithm that solves your problem? If your question is "I have a recursive algorithm and I need to make it iterative, how do I do that?", we can certainly give you some strategies for that. But this question needs to be made much more clear.

Comment: Also, if you can say why you want to avoid the recursive solution, that would help. Usually for these sorts of problems the recursive solution is short, understandable and elegant, and the iterative solution is a mess. Why do you want to avoid the short, elegant, understandable solution?

Comment: **Note** : This question is on the verge of being closed, there is a lock of response and clarification. Please read [ask]

Comment: Ok so this is some type of combination thing where you want to have all the combinations of `*` and `~` in the output, however its still kind of weird, id expect more combinations. ie `patrick~portland~vic~`

Comment: @TheGeneral - you are right... i haven't put the last one...which will be 
patrick~portland~vic~. I will update the question

Comment: Ok i have voted to reopen the question

Comment: Wouldn't that simply be the Cartesian product by using word count and binary representation (i.e * or ~) ?

Comment: Full demo here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/3gyRal note .net fiddle is playing up, however if you edit it, it will work, i think its the named tuples

Comment: @user2260040 - You should not post solutions in your question - you should do so as answer. That lets everyone know that the question has an answer when they search.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Would have done that, but the question was waiting to be reopened.

Comment: @user2260040 - You can certainly do it now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the solution that you posted in your question I thought it seemed a bit verbose. I thought I'd try to shorten.

Here it is:

```
string streetName = "patrick portland vic";

string[] split = streetName.Split(' ');
string[] chars = { "*", "~" };

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> choices = split.Select(n => chars.Select(c => $"{n}{c}"));

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result = choices.CartesianProduct();
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is more elegant.